# Pass argument to parameter from text box in UI (Flash, AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, parameter-passing

I'm currently learing to program in AS3 in Flash CS6 (I have no previous programming experience), and now I'm trying to pass an argument to a parameter from a text box in the UI.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
btnKnapp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, skrivUt(int(txtInput.text)));
function skrivUt(x:int)
{
    for(var i:int=1; i<=5; i++)
    {   
        var output:String = "";
        for(var j:int=0; j<x; j++)
        {
            output += String(i);
        }
        trace(output);
        txtOutput.appendText(output + "\n");
        output = "";
    }
}
```

So I want to execute the `skrivUt` function, and use the integer written in the `txtInput` text box as the `x` parameter,when I press the button `btnKnapp`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way that I'm using to pass parameters to EventListener.

```
btnKnapp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextfuncWithParams(skrivUt, int(txtInput.text)));

function nextfuncWithParams(nextfunc: Function, params: int): Function{
  return function(): void{
    nextfunc(params);
  }
}

function skrivUt(x:int): void
{
    // Your logic
}
```

If you want to pass multiple params, use Object type like below.

```
var obj: Object = new Object();
obj.param1 = "Some String param";
obj.param2 = 123;
obj.param3 = false;
btnKnapp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextfuncWithParams(skrivUt, obj));

function nextfuncWithParams(nextfunc: Function, params: Object): Function{
  return function(): void{
    nextfunc(params);
  }
}

function skrivUt(params: Object): void
{
    trace(params.param1);
    trace(params.param2);
    trace(params.param3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code will definitely work

```
btnKnapp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, skrivUt);
function skrivUt(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var x:int = int(txtInput.text);
    for(var i:int=1; i<=5; i++)
    {   
        var output:String = "";
        for(var j:int=0; j<x; j++)
        {
            output += String(i);
        }
        trace(output);
        txtOutput.appendText(output + "\n");
        output = "";
    }
}
```